# android client-server(socket) response from the server is null

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask, client-server

//Server methods

```
public static void searchMethodCatcher()
{
  try
  {
 clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
 isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),charset);
 br = new BufferedReader(isr);
 String str = br.readLine();
   if(str.charAt(0) == '{')
   {
      extendetSearchSystem(str);
   }
   else {simpleSearchListener(str);}    
 }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
public static void simpleSearchListener(String str)
{
  String result = str;
        System.out.println(line);

  try {
        clientSocket.shutdownInput();
        pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
        pw.write("DONE");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void serverListener(int port)
{
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_WORK);
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Could not listen on port"+ PORT_WORK);
            }
            while(isRun)
            {
                searchMethodCatcher();
               // simpleSearchListener();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

//Client asyncTast clas

```
 class ServerWorker extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Wrapper> {
    public int flag = 0, i = 0;
    public String[] tarr;
    public Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
    public String jsonResult,temp;
    public JSONObject jsonObject;
    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    flag = 2;
                } else {
                    printWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    printWriter.write(line);
                    printWriter.flush();
                    clientSocket.shutdownOutput();


                  //  clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
                    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    Log.e("READY?",br.ready()+" INPUT?" + clientSocket.isInputShutdown());
                    String message = br.readLine();
                    if(br.readLine()!=null)
                    Log.e("LINE IS",br.readLine()+"");
                    else{ Log.e("ERROR","br.readLine is null")
                    }
                    clientSocket.close();

                }
            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                flag = 1;
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return w;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper wrapper) {
        super.onPostExecute(wrapper);

    }
 }
}
```

So.When I run the server on the pc and client on the phone , and then sends the message I get the following. 
Server get message normal: [Server logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydOcS.jpg)

But response from server to phone is always null
[client logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqh7V.jpg)

I think i do something wrong with Input/Output streams. Pls help me to solve this issue./

**Client Logs** `11-15 22:29:31.750  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Can't open keycharmap file
11-15 22:29:31.750  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Error loading keycharmap file
11-15 22:29:31.750  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap
11-15 22:29:33.257  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem I/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ cscCountry is not German : SEK
11-15 22:29:33.359  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ No keyboard for id -1
11-15 22:29:33.359  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap
11-15 22:29:35.289  16011-16011/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem I/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ cscCountry is not German : SEK
11-15 22:29:40.578  16011-25796/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem E/READY?﹕ false INPUT?false
11-15 22:29:41.976  16011-25796/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem E/ERROR﹕ br.readLine is null`

**Server logs** `/192.168.0.8
iphone
Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 7 895 - 14 500 грн
Apple iPhone 6 16GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-16gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 13 199 - 30 200 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 64GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-64gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 20 043 - 27 816 грн
Apple iPhone 5 16GB (Black): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5-16gb-black/
Диапазон цен: 6 099 - 8 299 грн
Apple iPhone 6 64GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-64gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 15 782 - 25 457 грн
Apple iPhone 6 16GB (Gold): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-16gb-gold/
Диапазон цен: 14 271 - 20 999 грн
Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (Gold): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-gold/
Диапазон цен: 8 555 - 13 640 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-16gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 17 220 - 23 520 грн
Apple iPhone 5 16GB (White): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5-16gb-white/
Диапазон цен: 6 099 - 10 417 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 64GB (Rose Gold): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-64gb-rose-gold/
Диапазон цен: 20 160 - 29 551 грн
Apple iPhone 5S 32GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-32gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 9 018 - 15 750 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Rose Gold): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-16gb-rose-gold/
Диапазон цен: 17 349 - 23 520 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Gold): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-16gb-gold/
Диапазон цен: 17 145 - 23 520 грн
Apple iPhone 6s Plus 64GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-plus-64gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 24 630 - 33 450 грн
Apple iPhone 5C 16GB (White): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5c-16gb-white/
Диапазон цен: 6 048 - 11 250 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 128GB (Space Gray): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-128gb-space-gray/
Диапазон цен: 22 200 - 31 152 грн
Apple iPhone 6 16GB (Silver): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-16gb-silver/
Диапазон цен: 14 250 - 22 015 грн
Apple iPhone 6s 64GB (Silver): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-64gb-silver/
Диапазон цен: 20 050 - 27 816 грн
Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (Silver): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-white/
Диапазон цен: 8 399 - 14 750 грн
Apple iPhone 6 64GB (Silver): http://hotline.ua/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-64gb-silver/
Диапазон цен: 15 531 - 21 649 грн
Results count is 20
Results product is [Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 6 16GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 6s 64GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 5 16GB (Black) , Apple iPhone 6 64GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 6 16GB (Gold) , Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (Gold) , Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 5 16GB (White) , Apple iPhone 6s 64GB (Rose Gold) , Apple iPhone 5S 32GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Rose Gold) , Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Gold) , Apple iPhone 6s Plus 64GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 5C 16GB (White) , Apple iPhone 6s 128GB (Space Gray) , Apple iPhone 6 16GB (Silver) , Apple iPhone 6s 64GB (Silver) , Apple iPhone 5S 16GB (Silver) , Apple iPhone 6 64GB (Silver) ]
Results price is [7 895 - 14 500 грн , 13 199 - 30 200 грн , 20 043 - 27 816 грн , 6 099 - 8 299 грн , 15 782 - 25 457 грн , 14 271 - 20 999 грн , 8 555 - 13 640 грн , 17 220 - 23 520 грн , 6 099 - 10 417 грн , 20 160 - 29 551 грн , 9 018 - 15 750 грн , 17 349 - 23 520 грн , 17 145 - 23 520 грн , 24 630 - 33 450 грн , 6 048 - 11 250 грн , 22 200 - 31 152 грн , 14 250 - 22 015 грн , 20 050 - 27 816 грн , 8 399 - 14 750 грн , 15 531 - 21 649 грн ]
Results links is [/mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-16gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-64gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5-16gb-black/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-64gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-16gb-gold/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-gold/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-16gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5-16gb-white/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-64gb-rose-gold/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-32gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-16gb-rose-gold/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-16gb-gold/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-plus-64gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5c-16gb-white/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-128gb-space-gray/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-16gb-silver/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6s-64gb-silver/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-white/ , /mobile-mobilnye-telefony-i-smartfony/apple-iphone-6-64gb-silver/ ]`

Comment: 'clientSocket.shutdownOutput();'. What is that for?

Comment: Please post relevant pieces of the logs here.

Comment: Disables the output stream for this socket.
11-15 21:36:34.906    1492-1677/com.kiskin.vlad.kvsearchsystem E/ERROR﹕ br.readLine is null

Comment: One line is not a relevant piece. Don't post as a comment. Put all relevant info in your post.

Comment: 'else{ Log.e("ERROR","br.readLine is null"). No. else{ Log.e("ERROR","br.readLine is NOT null")

Comment: 'pw.write("DONE");'. That does not send a line. Your client is trying to read a line with  br.readLine();. That will only succeed if the server closes the connection. Which it does indeed.

Comment: Mmm it's different as the server tries to read a line with String str = br.readLine();. But the client is not sending a line with '  printWriter.write(line);'. Or.. we cannot see the contents of line... Maybe your shut down output is doing something like that but then it's strange code for me.

Comment: But i dont have exception in my logs... i can post my client logs but it does not make sense.  yep  you are right, must be != there. I have corrected,but it does not change anything. br.readLine() is null but must be "DONE".

Comment: Just post server and client logs here if you cannot solve the problem your self and want help.

Comment: 'clientSocket.shutdownOutput();'. Remove all that shut down from your code. I've never seen it used. Try to do without. Reread my comments.

Comment: if i delete clientSocket.shutdownOutput() outputStream never close and the server dont receives the data before closing the application client ( closing the socket )

Comment: Indeed that is what i told you before: in order to be able to read lines you have to send them first. So add "\n" to your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String message = br.readLine();
if(br.readLine()!=null)
    Log.e("LINE IS",br.readLine()+"");
else{
     Log.e("ERROR","br.readLine is null");
}
```

You're reading lines and throwing them away. What you should be testing and logging above is the content of `message`. Not reading `message`, reading another line and testing that, and logging the result of yet a third `readLine()`. As the server doesn't even send one line, let alone three, you're never going to get anything but null for the second two `readLine()` calls.

NB Don't do I/O in the `accept()` thread. Every accepted socket should be handled in its own thread.